# Email PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php

I'm trying to set an if statement in my email body but I got this error. This is the part of the body message in my PHP code:

```
$body = <<<EOD
<strong>Tipo contatto:</strong> $contacttype <br>
EOD;
$body .= $contacttype == "telefonopref" ? "<strong>Chiamatemi in questo orario:</strong>".$orariotel."<br>"; <!-- line with error -->
$body.= <<<EOD
    <strong>Contatto:</strong> $contatto <br>
    <strong>Messaggio:</strong> $message <br>
EOD;
```

What's wrong? Any suggestion on how I should write it correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the second part of your ternary statement

Comment: You have forgotten the else part of the ternary expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator works like this:

```
$something = $condition ? 'this if true' : 'this if false';
```

You just need to add the `: ''` at the end of the line (before the semicolon) for your else statement.

Comment: There is no such thing like an *"inline if"*. The [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is an operator, [`if` is a control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). Operators and statements are different concepts, with different purposes in a program. They cannot be interchanged.

Comment: Thanks Stevish, complete answer!

Comment: @axiac Thanks, I couldn't think of the word "ternary", All I could think of was "Tertiary" and I KNEW that wasn't right!

Answer (score 3):

? : condition is missing..

```
$body = <<<EOD
<strong>Tipo contatto:</strong> $contacttype <br>
EOD;
$body .= $contacttype == "telefonopref" ? "<strong>Chiamatemi in questo orario:</strong>".$orariotel."<br>" : ""; 
$body.= <<<EOD
    <strong>Contatto:</strong> $contatto <br>
    <strong>Messaggio:</strong> $message <br>
EOD;
```